How can I see the missing contents of initrd in Debian 12 (bookworm)?
I have a 73M initrd, but it only contains 6.9M of files.
Most of what I expect to be in the initrd is missing.
root@debian:/tmp/tmp# ls -lAh /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73M Mar  4 08:39 /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64

root@debian:/tmp/tmp# cat /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64 | cpio -idmv 
kernel
kernel/x86
kernel/x86/microcode
kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc
kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin
14080 blocks

root@debian:/tmp/tmp# du -h
4.0K    ./kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc
6.9M    ./kernel/x86/microcode
6.9M    ./kernel/x86
6.9M    ./kernel
6.9M    .

How can I see the other 66M+ of files?
